# How to make multiple connections to Impinj RFID reader?

Tags: rfid, reader

I'm working with Impinj Octane SDK for Java for a web app that requires connecting to the reader in every single session, but accessing to different anthennas.

Is there any way to do that without exceptions being raised?

Answer (score 0):

That is unfortunately not possible, the Octane SDK uses a Low Level Reader Protocol under the hood, and LLRP only supports a single connection.

You need to build your own data 'broker', or use a platform like Nedap Harmony (nedap-harmony.com) that brings data to the cloud, and makes it easy to integrate the RFID actions into a web app.